# Viewing one's /review/ performance

Tags: discussion, review, review-abuse

Is it possible to somehow (*easily*, but doesn't have to be) view or visualize my /review/ performance?

I found an interesting question, [Lock questions in the review queue while being reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149869/lock-questions-in-the-review-queue-while-being-reviewed), which basically talks about a user taking a long time to review a post causing the review opportunity to *timing out*, and give the review to somebody else; however, that somebody else does a quick review and moves on.

My mind started wondering: *how many times have I been **that** somebody else?*

---

In essence, I'm wondering if there is a way (even if through [Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)) to view the following of posts I reviewed:

- Edits by someone other than the author, which occurred *after* I performed a "No Action Needed" review or an "I'm Done" action;
- Questions/answers closed/deleted by someone other than the author, where I did *not* cast a flag;
- (**important!**) Posts deleted through the use of a helpful *spam* flag, where I didn't flag spam.

---

Aside from personal benefit to some curious users (like myself), it *may* be used by mods or others (devs?) to possibly detect abuse, etc.

PS. This is tagged as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), because it might not be worth a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) yet.