# Lines of code lost in formatting?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, code-formatting

I was Reviewing Suggested Edits, and got one on this question: [what makes my spinner view look different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809696/what-makes-my-spinner-view-look-different)

It looked clear-cut that the suggestor had added some code. So I chose Invalid Edit. Without that I'd have considered Too Minor, as there were still grammar errors in the post.

Checking back shortly afterwards, the edit had been Accepted. A couple of the Acceptors are fearsome Edit Reviewers, so I agonised on further action.

Eventually, I did a Rollback, and started to edit. And found the "added" code in the edit I was doing.

I then discovered the option to look at the Source, so I did that for the original post. Yes, the code was there, but it was not visible through any version of the edit until it was formatted in the edit I'd reversed. So another Rollback. Edit that for the grammar. Forgot the title, but that's another story.

So, a bug, a feature?

More importantly, if I see what appears to be code that has been added, do I have to look at the Source of the original just to check that it has actually been added? This one, [Lock questions in the review queue while being reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149869/lock-questions-in-the-review-queue-while-being-reviewed), indicates the problems inherent in that (by the time I do that, the Suggestion will already be Approved/Rejected).

Comment: Just to clarify, is [this the review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3676832) you are talking about?

Comment: @chuex, yes, that is it.

Comment: anytime I see strange code, I check both "views" of the edit. If you look at the top of the review link, you see two view options: "rendered output", and "markdown". I make it a habit to toggle between the two.

Comment: @chuex, OK, but looking at Revision 3 I don't see all the lines of the original code. Not until I look at the Source.

Comment: Are you looking at the edit (revision) history, or the edit review that I linked to? you should look at the latter. (the latter is what you see during the review.)

Comment: @chuex OK, thanks. Noted for the future. I didn't know code could get hidden like that. Now I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML tags are hidden from the default view (you can't see any `<h1>` or `<br />` tags either) since it wouldn't make much sense most of the time.

In your case, `<LinearLayout` didn't have the required whitespace to be formatted as code which means it got interpreted as text instead. Afterwards since it is an HTML tag in a text area, it was hidden and applied (nothing to apply here though).

The only thing that should be considered a bug here is the fact that the next lines are in code tags, even though there was no whitespace between that and the previous line with the HTML tag.

When it looks like code is added and it starts with a `<` (and you might expect to see an HTML tag), you should always check the other view which has the literal representation of what constructed that post.