# Edit history shows an edit that I can't see on the question

Tags: bug, revisions-list, caching

Relates to this question: [Encoding and decoding get parameters in CodeIgniter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142584/encoding-and-decoding-get-parameters-in-codeigniter-not-working)

The screenshot below shows how I can currently see the page. Note the last editor and the presence of the *PLZ HLP ME REAL SOON* statement:

---

[image: Page as I see it]

---

But when I look at the edit history, I see this:

---

[image: edit history]

---

Of course, like most problems **this is probably caching**. But is this to be expected? I've never seen it before.

Comment: That's weird because even the name of the last editor is not showing(default locale) as if his edit was not accepted!

Comment: Sidenote: Can we get a mod to bring the bad-review-hammer down on the people who approved [the edit that added that in](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3814690)? None of them should have rubber stamped it as it was.

Comment: Sequencing. Whilst the good reviewer was editing, three others Approved. Good edit tossed (note missing Community-diamond approval) but, buggily, edit history updated (earlier than toss?). Until something is done about this, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149869/lock-questions-in-the-review-queue-while-being-reviewed, bad reviewers can always clobber someone's work. New way to do it... nice spot.

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the edit was approved before he actually submitted his improvement edit. The race condition may have caused the system not to save a rendered copy of the post for display using his edited version.