# Can reviewers have reserved time when they're reviewing a post?

Tags: feature-request, review

We've been [discussing the quality of some reviews on Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8421/reviewers-need-to-be-mindful-of-their-actions). Some of us were getting frustrated that some users were smashing through 20 reviews in a minute so I decided to lay down the law.

Aaaanyway, as part of this [one of our newer reviewers](https://askubuntu.com/users/16395/rmano) brought up the problem that if they take too long being diligent (looking into duplicates *properly*, checking rules, etc) there's a very good chance that somebody else will have reviewed that post and their decision (and the time that went into it) is wasted. That doesn't seem like a fair reward for what is an otherwise thankless task.

So I'm suggesting the a review "reservation" system so only one person can review something at once:

- Once something is opened in review, it becomes unavailable to other users to review. That includes other queues. A reservation or lock should be against a post, not a post in a queue.
- The reviewer should get, for example, two minutes of alone-time with a post.
- If they review before their time is up, the lock goes away.
- If they're still reviewing when their time runs out, a notification should pop up (audio too?) and allow them to request an extension... Perhaps with 10 seconds grace to stop somebody else being allocated something.
- Questions are simply allocated on a first-unlocked-post basis.
- There should be a safety-limit on the number of times something can be review-locked or extended so that somebody can't wrongfully extend the life of a bad post (offensive/spam/etc) by gumming up review.

It sounds messy (and there's certainly some concurrency issues if you've split the servers out horizontally) but data-wise, it's actually not *too* hard to implement (speaking as somebody who has implemented an edit-lock system before).

Above all else, it shows reviewers the respect they deserve for a job that few of us really want to do.

Comment: A 30 second timer per review sounds appropriate.

Comment: I really like that idea.  I run into the same issue with proof reading questions.  If it's a short question, making sure it's proper English can be done really quickly, but for longer ones, a lock would be nice.

Comment: There's been [previous discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149869/228098) on the subject, although there wasn't an official SE response. Related to your last bullet point, I would encourage reading Gnat's response there.

Comment: I still think that 30 seconds is really too short a time for a mindful review. Especially if you choose to improve it.

Comment: Maybe 30 seconds that can be renewed (automatically) for another 30 seconds if still on the page, repeatedly up to 10 minutes?

Comment: Yep, it's pretty upsetting to spend some time trying to keep the quality, only to being overrun by robo-reviewers (specially on the Suggested Edits queue).