# Require more info when rejecting an edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

The edit approval/rejection process is too opaque.  The reason given says, "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."  This reason doesn't say whether it's incorrect or should be a comment.  If it is incorrect, they rejector should have to explain what is incorrect about it.

If this should be a comment then I'm really misunderstanding something.  I would think comments should further discussion, where as edits help to avoid accidental or beginner errors.  This edit does not change any functionality or further the discussion.  It simply cleans up the answer's code slightly to make it safer for the (extremely likely) copy/paste scenario.

Thoughts?

Comment: The problem that happens is people are lazy. So if you put up barriers, people subvert them. a bunch of laziness sadly. If you find a good way to enforce some useful checking, that'd be good

Comment: But I think there's a problem with people making too many minor trivial edits

Comment: Yeah, I think suggestion linked in @Pëkka's answer combined with this would be pretty effective.  There could also be some limiting on how quickly you can repeatedly accept.  This might slow things down a little bit, but there are still plenty of others to review and accept and it would improve the quality of the experience on both sides.

Comment: @Adel, maybe the fix for that it to just not reward edits with reputation.  They should improve clarity, not be a quick way for spammers to bump themselves up by suggesting thousands of pointless edits.  Maybe you could +1 edits or something if you really feel the editor deserves the bump.

Comment: Your image link is broken.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with the spirit of your suggestion, but there is a rampant problem with ["robo-reviewers"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=robo-reviewers) approving anything they come across.

Because [there is currently no locking mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149869/lock-questions-in-the-review-queue-while-being-reviewed), a good reviewer taking the time to explain a rejection may lead to the edit getting approved in the meantime.

Comment: You could still separate out "incorrect" from "attempting to comment/reply" though.  I never really did understand why the two were smushed together; they're really two different things.

Comment: That's true. ---

Comment: True.  Wouldn't that be true for reject as well, though?

Comment: The locking mechanism is a very good idea.

Comment: Another option is letting the reviewer edit the rejection reason later so he rejects quickly with generic reason then takes his/her time to explain.

Comment: I agree with the answer. I usually don't have time to finish reading all the changes before they get approved by robo-reviewers.