# The current item is automatically skipped if exited review page and re-open it

Tags: support, review

I am reviewing something when I accidentally press the site logo, which brings me to the front page of the site. Then I click the review button to the left of my info (avatar/rep/badge) and find that the number of the "number of review list items" is decreased by one, and the post I was reviewing no longer shows up **in the rest of the queue**. I think it has been automatically skipped when the review page was interrupted.

To reproduce:

Go to a site where you have access to a review, preferably FP. Note the number and click the title *First Posts* to obtain the first review item. Now don't do anything and click the site logo (or simply close the page). Re-navigate to the review page (`//something.stackexchange.com/review`) and you'll find the number decreased by one. If possible, you can finish the queue amd you won't find the "skipped" rev item.

Comment: First Posts queue is very dynamic on Stack Overflow. It's always around 10 items, and since it requires only a single reviewer, each item is completed in matter of minutes. Also, once you enter the review it's "locked" for several minutes and won't be displayed to anyone.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I review on Android.SE where it isn't that "dynamic".

Comment: I see there are 11 items there now, and like I said, the temporary lock is most likely the reason you don't see the item again. Try 10 minutes later and I'm pretty sure you'll get the item again, if it wasn't yet reviewed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It seems like your "locked for several minutes" is the correct answer. I'm going to accept it if you post it.

Comment: Done, added to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, only explicitly pressing the "Skip"  button cause actual skipping of the item. (i.e. the item will no longer be displayed for you, unless you browse it directly.)

You see a different review item because the system is showing a review item **in random**.

Also, important to mention that as of April 2015, [review items are temporary locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252713/152859). So if you enter a review item, nobody else (including yourself) will get that item for several minutes when going to the review queue. Trying again after several minutes should "fix" this.

Comment: I edited the question. More details.

Comment: @iDebug I see. But what list you talk about? There is no list of review items, we get them one by one.

Comment: Say there's a number 5 in the queue list and I click one. I see a post named A then click the logo. After going to the queue list the number is 4 and I go through the list, reviewing B, C, D and E.

Comment: By "queue list" I mean `/review`.

Comment: @iDebug so it means that the item was already reviewed. If you remember the title of the post 10k user can look through the review history to find it.

Comment: Then what's the result of the review?

Comment: @iDebug you can "prove" you didn't Skip the item by going to the review queue history yourself, you'll see your own actions there.

Comment: @iDebug I can't know, first give title of the post and what review it was, e.g. First Posts, Suggested Edits