# Red bullet indicator appears but (I think) I am not banned

Tags: support, review

I see a red bullet in one of my review queues (see attached screenshot). Reading from other posts on this site, I understand that this might mean that I'm (or, more properly, I was) banned from the review queue.

Is it so? If the answer is yes, why? If not, what does it mean?

A similar question posted on [Cross Validated Meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6433/56940) got no answers so far and one of the mods suggested that this site is a better place for such a question.

[image]

Comment: Has it been an hour since you did your last review? Then perhaps you can be running into something like described in this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/369802 at point 3. How many active reviewers are there on cross validated? If there are 'enough', the threshold that point speaks of may not have been raised, and you see the dot?

Comment: The red dot does not indicate a ban: it indicates that that review queue has many tasks and reviews there are particularly needed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/643262

Comment: Actually, a few seconds before seeing this I flagged four non-answers. Then I came back to the queue, clicked the bullet and now review appeared (as in the screenshot). So @wimi I'm not sure that was the reason.

Comment: @AntonMenshov thanks for the pointer, quite a vague answer in there though...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell, yes, there are many reviewers on xvalidated. I think Glorfindel is right.

Comment: You would know if you were banned. See the [screenshots of the drop-down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351118/323179).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/282094), read starting at: "3. reviewers warned of same tasks twice ...".

Comment: thank your @Rob, the same post was suggested by  
Tinkeringbell in a previous comment. No that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I believe that the question "I understand that this might mean that I'm (or, more properly, I was) banned from the review queue. --- Is it so? If the answer is yes, why? If not, what does it mean?" is answered by #3 or 4 (and its link to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149869/282094). Either: the indicator was falsely triggered, you've done the review and can't do it twice, you were ninjad, you ran out of reviews, or the post is your own and have a conflict with it or an opposing prior review. ---- **We** can tell you how, but only a moderator (or staff) can tell you about the specifics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you're not eligible to review the item. That can happen because of the following reasons:

- it's one of your own posts which is under review
- you flagged the post earlier as Very Low Quality or Not An Answer
- you skipped the review item
- you opened the review item recently but didn't take any action

The dot color (red, gray or transparent) and the number of reviews on the /review page are computed for all users and cached for a couple of minutes; it's only when you open the specific review queue that you know whether there are actual things to review for you.

Comment: I think the second is the most plausible; see also my comments above.